# strstr() с обратной стороны

Tags: php, строки

Как обрезать строку с правой стороны?   
`strstr($i, $y, true)` не работает из за низкой версии PHP

Comment: А причём тут версия PHP?

Comment: @VladD это работает только в версии 5.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`substr( $i, 0, strpos( $i , ".jpg") )` ?

ззыж про расширение тоже верно Ж)

Comment: нет,ребят, вы меня не поняли...
после .jpg идет еще сивмолов ~3000 и их колв-во всегда разное мне нужно отсеч именно по вхождению строки

Comment: ну и? вернет строку отрезанную до первого вхождения `.jpg`, если использовать `strrpos`, то по последнее вхождение... почитайте описание функций хоть... либо уточняйте вопрос, на данный момент наши варианты соответствуют вашему заданию.

Comment: @thunder Спасибо большое все работает))

Answer (score 0):

А что мешает найти индекс при помощи [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)/[`strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php), и взять подстроку?

```
substr($i, 0, strrpos($i, $y))
```

Для PHP версии младше 5, нужен цикл, см комментарий [[@thunder](/users/9040/thunder)](/users/9040/thunder):

```
$pos = 0;
$found = false;
do
{
    $newpos = strpos($i, $y, $pos);
    if ($newpos !== false)
    {
        $pos = $newpos;
        $found = true;
    }
}
while ($newpos !== false);
if ($found)
    $i = substr($i, 0, $pos);
else
    ...
```

Comment: предположим мне нужно отсечь .jpg в http://distilleryimage10.instagram.com/5c4b68b65d8411e2b22122000a9f12bd_7.jpg
КАК?

Comment: @igolka97: `.jpg` -- это константа, или переменная? Или вы хотите отрезать расширение?

Comment: substr( $i, 0, strpos( $i , ".jpg") ) ?

Comment: @VladD да - это константа и мне надо получить  http://distilleryimage10.instagram.com/5c4b68b65d8411e2b22122000a9f12bd_7

Comment: @igolka97: смотрите в камент @thunder выше. Только надо `strrpos`. (Обновил ответ.)

Comment: @VladD может не прокатить, раз от версии пхп зависит

> 5.0.0  The needle may now be a string of more than one character.
> 5.0.0  The offset parameter was introduced.

Comment: @thunder: добавил цикл :)

Answer (score 0):

```
substr($string, $from, $count);
```

Comment: Дополню ответ @ToRcH565

    <?php
    $rest = substr("abcdef", -1);    // возвращает "f"
    $rest = substr("abcdef", -2);    // возвращает "ef"
    $rest = substr("abcdef", -3, 1); // возвращает "d"
    ?>


Comment: @thunder мне нужен поиск по вхождению строки а не отсчет символов(

Comment: привел пример выше, какая разница, это основы)